# how to rewrite this convenient escape special characters function for regexp

Tags: php, regex

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400316/80353), in any regular expression, I need to escape these characters outside the character classes.

```
.^$*+?()[{\|
```

I have the following:

```
$search = "App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');";

$replace = $search . "\nApp::uses('CrudControllerTrait', 'Crud.Lib');";
$escaped_search = escape_special_characters($search);

$patterns = array('/' . $escaped_search . '/');
$replacements = array($replace);
$file_contents = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $file_contents);
```

The `preg_replace` will fail because I need to escape the `(` inside the `$search` variable.

Which is why I have this function:

```
function escape_special_characters($search) {
  $special_characters = array(
    ".", "^", "$", 
    "*", "+", "?",
    "(", ")", "[",
    "{", "|", "\\"
  );

  $character_array = str_split($search);
  $string_array = array();
  foreach ($character_array as $character) {
    if (in_array($character, $special_characters)) {
      $string_array[] = "\\";
    }
    $string_array[] = $character;
  }

  return implode("", $string_array);

}
```

**My question is whether there is a better way to do this other than my `escape_special_characters` function?**

========================================================================

*SOME BACKGROUND:*

**Why did I write my code as such above?**

My purpose is to look for the line `App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');` and write the line `App::uses('CrudControllerTrait', 'Crud.Lib');` ***AFTER*** it.

Comment: Is `preg_quote` not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a function to escape the "ugly dozen" characters in a pattern.

You have two way to do this:

```
$pattern = '~' . preg_quote($search, '~') . '~'; // to escape special characters and the delimiter
```

or

```
$pattern = '~\Q' . $search . '\E~'; // to ignore special characters
```

However, I don't understand why you use the `preg_replace()` function instead of the `str_replace()` function since you seems to look for a literal string.

Comment: You should also provide preg_quote with your delimiter to make sure its handlede propperly so in your case $pattern = '~'.preg_quote($search,'~').'~';

Comment: @JesperBunnyJensen: Thanks! I didn't know that it was possible to do that!